# Error Saving Database Using SQLiteDataAdapter Update

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I'm trying to save database when closing form. I don't have a dataset and I'm using bindingsource. Here's my function:

```
private void SaveData()
{
    try
    {
        sqliteDataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
    }
    catch (ConstraintException)
    {
        DataRow[] rowErrors = dataTable.GetErrors();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("YourDataTable Errors:"
            + rowErrors.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < rowErrors.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rowErrors[i].RowError);

            foreach (DataColumn col in rowErrors[i].GetColumnsInError())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(col.ColumnName
                    + ":" + rowErrors[i].GetColumnError(col));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting error: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.dll
How can I fix this?

Comment: Check if the exception contains an InnerException and post the message of this inner exception

Comment: No I'm not getting innerexception. How can I check it? If I type catch (Exception ex) { ... I'm not getting any errors but database won't be saved.

Comment: `System.Data.dll`error probably because you are referencing the incorrect `Assembly` for example if this were SQL SERVER you would have to add reference in the using as well as manually add the reference for `using System.Data.SqlClient` look up the proper one for your `Sqlite`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried adding "using" statement but I couldn't find System.Data.SQLite either sqlite in reference manager.